# How to compute vector $d\vec r$ in terms of parameter $t$ , that is how to apply directly the line integral definition ( without using $\vec {r'}dt$)

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

This question deals with the computation of line integrals.

One method is to translate the expression $\int_C \vec {\bf F} \bf. d\vec r$ as $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec {\bf F} \bf {.}\bf {\vec {\bf r'}}$ $dt$. I think this method is the most common one.

In this video from the MIT's lecture series on [Multivariable calculus: Path dependence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBuIwfdoOn0),  the instructor uses the first expression, that is, he dots directly vector $F$ with the differential $d\vec r$.

In the exercise that is corrected , the path is a straight line
from point $(1,1)$ to point $(2,4)$.

Using $t$ as parameter , we get : $\vec r(t)  = < t, 3t-2> $.

The instructor directly writes $d\vec r = <dt, 3dt>$.

How to explain this?

Comment: This depends on the parametrization of your path.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are clear with the 2nd part of the line integral: that is

[image]

and what to know why $d\vec r$, $dt$ thing

[image]

So, there no a ground rule that you have to take a variable $t$ to solve line integrals you can still go with the Cartesian $x, y$

$$\vec F = <xy, x^2+ y^2>$$
Equation of line passing through $(1,1)$ & $(2,4)$ $$y = 3x-2 \implies \color{red}{dy = 3dx}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\int_c \vec F d\vec r
& = \int_c \left(x(3x-2)\hat i + (x^2+(3x-2)^2)\hat j\right)(\hat i dx +  \hat j dy)\\
& = \int_c \left((3x^2-2x)\hat i + (10x^2-12x+4)\hat j\right)(\hat i dx + \hat j (3dx))\\
& = \int_c \left((3x^2-2x)dx + (10x^2-12x+4)3dx\right)\\
& = \int_c \left(3x^2-2x+30x^2-36x+12\right)dx\\
& = \int_c \left(33x^2-38x+12\right)dx\\ \text{Same as if you take variable 't'}\\
& = \text{Here 'x' goes from 1} \to 2 \\
& = \int_1^2 (33x^2-38x+12)dx\\
& = \left[11x^3-19x^2+12x\right]_1^2\\
& = \left[11(7)-19(3) + 12(1)\right]\\
& = 77-57+12 \\
& = 32
\end{align*}$$

Rest of the thing are just algebra and integral substitution

However, if you want to know why $d\vec r = (\hat idx+\hat jdy)$
then it's the infinitesimal change of position vector.
Hope this answers you question.